# Comparing two linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $h:X\to\Bbb C$ and $f:X\to\Bbb C$ be two bounded linear functions such that if for some $x\in X$ we have $f(x)=0$  then $h(x)=0$. Prove that there exists a $\lambda\in \Bbb{C}$ such that for any $x\in X$ we have $h(x)=\lambda f(x)$.

Comment: This is a purely algebraic statement, which *should* be true even without any boundedness assumption. Where have you gotten so far?

Comment: This isn't true. I think you want to take the set of linear *functionals* on $X$, instead.

Comment: @David David (the other one) is right: $Y$ should be the scalar field; otherwise the result is not true.

Comment: This is (for $Y = \mathbb{K}$) a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800638/writing-a-linear-functional-as-a-linear-combination/800680#800680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f=0$ then choose $\lambda=0$. If $f\neq0$ then let $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)\neq0$ or we may suppose that $f(x_0)=1$. For any $x\in X$ we have $f(x-f(x)x_0)=0$ and so $h(x-f(x)x_0)=0$. This means $h(x)=f(x)h(x_0)$. Thus it's enough to set $\lambda=h(x_0)$.